# javascript window.reload then window.location.href

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make a code in which the window reloads and then the location is changed, though i tried `window.location.reload(); window.location.href="#id"` but it didn't work because when the page will reload, the script won't run. 
 Actually i want to clear the POST data from the page and then change the location on the same page to an id.

Comment: Why not just change the URL, *then* trigger a reload?

Comment: i tried but, then it kept reloading..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have said, updating the `href` will trigger a reload, so manually calling `reload` isn't necessary. If you did want to go that way, it would require a conditional check to prevent infinite reloads you're seeing...say based on some parameter in the url like:

```
if (window.location.hash === '') {
    window.location.hash = '#id';
    window.location.reload();
} else {
    window.location.hash = '';
}
```

Just simply updating the `hash` won't cause a reload, so the following wouldn't work (it would just move to the location)

```
window.location.href = '#answer-28520707').
```

However, you could do something like this:

```
window.location.href = "?_reload" + Date.now() + "#answer-28520707"
```

The query parameter will cause the browser to refresh the page and the hash will jump to the new location.

If you'd like to test this, try pasting the above in a console or typing this in the address bar:

```
javascript:void(window.location.href = "?_reload" + Date.now() + "#answer-28520707")
```

(It should reload the page and scroll to this answer)

Comment: @MihirUjjainwal Let me start with `?_reload` first. The important part is the `?`, which is called a `query` parameter. If you need to send data to a server, typically you would use this. Something like `http://www.domain.com?name=Mihir&howCool=very`. The server will have access to `name` and `howCool`. What comes after the `?` is entirely up to you and honestly my answer could have been something as simple as `http://www.domain.com?r#id` to do what you want to do (`query` being `r` and the `#` (or hash) being your id). The `Date.now()` was a way to visually show the addressing being updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
window.location.href = "#id";
window.location.reload();
```

You don't need the reload first, the page will reload just by changing the location.href value.

Comment: Edited post, I think this is what you wanted to do :)

Comment: Could you update your question? I'm not sure exactly what you want to do? Why are you trying to change location?

Comment: I want to reload the page then change the location, but when i tried your code, my page kept loading.

Comment: Try putting the location you want to change to instead of #id, the # has special meaning in browsers, so it will not update the html, then you can remove location.reload(). example: `window.location.href = "http://google.com/"`
should redirect to google.

Comment: But, i want to change the location to a div, should i use `website.com#id`

Comment: All you need is `window.location.hash = "#id"`

Comment: The div needs to look something like this: `<div id="id">...</div>`

Comment: See other answer, it has the explanation !